# Flask send_file to Javascript File Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, flask, axios

Hello I'm trying to create a File object in javascript from the binary response I get from send_file on my flask backend.

Flask Endpoint

```
@app.route('/costTracker/file', methods=['POST'])
def costTrackerFile(token=None):
    body = request.get_json(force=True)
    if body.get('FILENAME', None) is None:
        return response(400, 'No Filename found', token)

    filename = body.get('ATTACHMENT', 'FILENAME')

    return send_file(os.path.join(
        app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], body.get('FOLDER', ''), body['FILENAME']), attachment_filename=filename)
```

React w/ axios

```
const [file,setFile] = React.useState<File | undefined>(undefined);
...
await axios.post('/costTracker/file',{
                FILENAME: '5c466663cc535cd3501e5aec495400b9af57235c581ac4e4fc1dc6d6792f2646.png', 
                ATTACHMENT: 'MicrosoftTeams-image.png',
                FOLDER: 'CostTracker'
            }).then(resp => {
                const { data } = resp;
                var f = new File([data], 'filename.png')
                console.log(f);
                setFile(f);
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

The key was in the axios call to set the responseType parameter to 'blob' then to create a File Object from the response.

```
axios
                .get('/download', { params, responseType: 'blob' })
                .then((resp) => {
                    const file = new File(
                        [resp.data],
                        params.attachment ?? params.filename
                    );
                    const ops_file: OPSFile = {
                        id: params.id,
                        file,
                        message: 'file uploaded successfully',
                        progress: 100,
                        statusCode: 100,
                    };
                    setUploads((old) => [
                        ...old.filter(({ id }) => id !== params.id),
                        ops_file,
                    ]);
                });
```